# Several clients confirmed transactions with the same hash

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, hash

We generate a personal bitcoin-address for a payment for each customer. For these purposes, we use the [Blockchain.Info API](https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive). Today it was discovered that in callback sent by the Blockchain.Info we received the confirmation of two facts of payments to **different** addresses, the transactions of which have the **same** hash.

In an attempt to find out the reason, we tried to track the transaction history, but found that its total amount is 11 BTC with dozens of outputs: https://blockchain.info/tx/10665471525e014c295c68dc56d8989fb3979272b60e53430155267e73162e51

So, I have a few questions:

1. Can transfers of bitcoins to different generated addresses have the
   same hash? Why?
2. Why does the transaction consist of a set of outputs, the total amount 
   of which is 11 BTC, which is hundreds of times the amount
   that customers had to pay us?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> Today it was discovered that in callback sent by the Blockchain.Info we received the confirmation of two facts of payments to different addresses, the transactions of which have the same hash.

You mean more than one customer paid you in a single transaction. There's nothing particularly unusual about that.

> Can transfers of bitcoins to different generated addresses have the same hash? Why?

Yes, they can. A single payment can produce a number of outputs, sending bitcoins to several different addresses.

> Why does the transaction consist of a set of outputs, the total amount of which is 11 BTC, which is hundreds of times the amount that customers had to pay us?

Because several customers paid you and several other people paid for other things in a single transaction. This is a way to save on fees.